# How to specify a pattern for autofilling cells in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to do some unusual autofill in excel.

- I want to autofill downward like in the following:

  =B5 &CHAR(10) &B6
  =B7 &CHAR(10) &B8
  =B9 &CHAR(10) &B10
- But excel does this instead:

  =B5 &CHAR(10) &B6
  =B6 &CHAR(10) &B7
  =B7 &CHAR(10) &B8

Answer (score 1):

I have Excel 2010. I used the Auto Fill option to select growth and make sure you fill in 1. You can access the Excel 2010 fill options by clicking on the home tab, finding the fill label and selecting series. So now it does the plus one you are looking for.

Comment: That does not work. It only works for non-formulaic entries. I tried it with just integers and it worked just fine.

Comment: weird. when i did it, it worked just the way you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it:

=INDIRECT("B" & 2*ROW()-5) & CHAR(10) & INDIRECT("B" & 2*ROW()-4)

"B" is column B and inside ROW() you select an entire row.